# Is Java serialization deterministic?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

If I have a class that implements `Serializable` such as:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    public String a;
    public String b;
}
```

Is using `ObjectOutputStream` to serialize of the object deterministic?

Comment: **"Deterministic"**? While that word has a definition, your question sets too little context for a meaningful answer to be given. It would help if you asked it in terms of clear expectations about the serialized/deserialized objects...

Comment: I'm not sure what else to add. Essentially, if a custom object with attributes (i.e. a, b) is serialized using an `ObjectOutputStream` will it always produce the same bytes for the same object? Will it produce any collisions?

Comment: Are you planning on writing code that depends on serialization being deterministic?

Comment: I'm using Dataflow & Apache Beam with custom objects. When you run a GroupBy in Dataflow on a Key Value pair, it uses the serialized bytes of the key to compare equality. Their out of the box [SerializableCoder](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/SerializableCoder.java#L190) documentation says that java serialization is not deterministic so I'm trying to understand under what scenarios it is and isn't. In short, yes I do need it to be deterministic, I want to understand when it isn't deterministic and why.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the example code.

```
 public class Foo implements Serializable {
   public String a;
  public String b;
}
```

In Test Class

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
     FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("saved_filename.dat");
     ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
     Foo f1=new Foo();
     oos.writeObject(f1);
    }catch(exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
      if(fos!=null) try{fos.close();}catch{IOException e){}
      if(oos!=null) try{oos.close();}catch{IOException e){}
    }
   }
}
```

Look like this.

Comment: Thank you. But, its still unclear to me if this method of serialization is deterministic

Comment: @user2317084 If you know that the data model is fixed and does not change much later, you can write a serialization format for each data model, which is called a schematic. (Well, I do not know exactly what you call it.)

Common examples include protocol buffers and Cap'n Proto. Schematic serialization methods can be divided again by performance or data size preference, which is more efficient than schemaless serialization, which will be discussed later.

Comment: @user2317084 Although it is not strictly a merit of the serialization method itself, it is also good that the data model can be filtered out most of the formatted data because it is fixed. However, there is a fundamental weakness that the new data can not be expressed unless the scalability is considered in advance, and there is a drawback that writing is a little annoying because the compiler for automatically generating the format is usually inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Java serialization is deterministic in the sense that one object will normally always result in the same byte stream when serialized by the builtin serialization mechanism. There are a few caveats:

- There are different versions of the protocol, and new Java versions may add new protocol versions.
- Java includes an object identity in the stream, to allow serializing of arbitrary graphs of objects. This identity is local to a single stream, so if you serialize an object twice into two separate streams, this identity number should be the same. But if this identity is part of 'the object' or part of some object header would depend on the circumstances.
- It is possible to define your own `readObject` and `writeObject` methods, or to implement the Externalizable interface, to do the serialization yourself. In that case the determinism depends entirely on whether your own code is deterministic.

I also arrived at this question because Apache Beam / Dataflow was telling me my serializer was not deterministic. In the case of Beam there's a different consideration: it sometimes requires serializers to be deterministic in the sense that two objects that compare equal with their `.equals()` method must also serialize to the same byte stream. (Probably so that the framework can do grouping based on the byte stream.) Since you must define your own `equals` method in Java you are free to have two objects compare equal even though they don't serialize to the same byte stream. For instance if the objects include some fields that are not taken into account when comparing for equality. Therefore Beam considers Java serialization as nondeterministic.